# group by aggregate function for multiplication

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

I want to aggregate 3 dataframes I have but instead of adding them together. I want to multiply 3 of them. is there a way to do it ?

i.e.

```
df=result.groupby(['name']).agg({'A':'sum','B':'sum'})
```

df1

```
      A  B   
tim   1  5
emma  3  7
```

df2

```
     A  B
tim  1  8
emma 1  2
```

result

```
     A  B
tim  2  13
emma 4  9
```

Instead of summing the two, I want to multiply them:

```
     A  B
tim  1  40
emma 12 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html):

```
df=result.groupby(['name']).agg({'A':'prod','B':'prod'})
```

If need also join them:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('name', as_index=False).prod()
```